# Printing pdf file directly from dos command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, printing, network-printers

I am trying to print a pdf file from dos, in windows xp.

```
C:\>print c:\dos.pdf /D:"\\jayaprada-pc\HP LaserJet 1018"

C:\dos.pdf is currently being printed
```

Its saying doc is being is printed. but no print is coming my printer.

Its showing the document in printer spooler window.

[image]

When giving print normally from adobe reader , print is coming fine.

What is wrong with my config.

Actually i want to print a pdf document from command line , so it wont pop up printer properties.

Suggest me any other alternative or third party tool that can be used print from command line in windows.

Comment: The Windows command-line interface is *not* called DOS, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t <file.pdf> <printer_name> <printer_driver> <printer_port>
```

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "D:\File.pdf" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "IP_192.168.10.110"
```

**Note:** 
To find the printer information, right click your printer and choose properties. 
In my case shown above, the printer name and driver.